better method of solving quadratic / cubic
Problem :
Let
$$\begin{align} f(x) &= x^4 - 8x^3 + 18x^2 \\ g(x) &= 9x^2 - 64x\end{align}$$
.
Define $h : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$, $h(x)=f(x)-ag(x)$ for some real number $a$.
If $h(x)$ has an inverse, find a maximum of $a$.

My Attempt :
The statement of this problem is easy : solving
$$h'(x)\geq 0 \quad (x>0)$$
and this means
$$4x^3 - 24x^2 + 2(18-9a)x + 64a \geq 0 \quad (x>0)$$
but this is quite messy. I tried to derivative $h'(x)$ once again and change problem to local minimum of $h'(x)$ is greater or equal to zero.
But root of $h''(x) = 0$ is very very messy, so I am trying to find a better method.

The reason why I suspect there is a better method is, WA says maximum is 2, which is nice answer.
Thanks for help.

What do you mean?  $h''(x)$ is just a quadratic.

@lulu I mean, let me call a root of $h''(x) = 0$ as $k$, then $h'(k)$ is too messy,

This might help: $h'(4)=16-8 a$

@Lozenges Can u give me some details?

$h'(4) \ge 0$ implies $a \le 2$.  Check that for $a=2$ , $h(x)$ has an inverse. see also the answer by @Anne Bauval

@Lozenges Amazing! Please post your answer.

From your first derivative:
$$h'(x)=4x^3-24x^2+2(18-9a)x+64a$$
We can rearrange this expression a bit:
$$h'(x)=4x\{x^2-6x+9(2-a)\}+64a$$
$$=4x\{x^2-6x+9-9+9(2-a)\}+64a$$
$$4x\{(x-3)^2+9(2-a)-9\}+64a$$
Now, you need ensure that for $x\geq 0$, $h'(x)>0$. For that to happen, look at the expression of $h'(x)$. For $x\geq 0$, $4x\geq 0$ holds. Now, $(x-3)$ is always positive, no matter what the value of $x$ is. We just need to ensure that , the total expression $(x-3)^2+9(2-a)-9$ remains positive.
For that, consider the smallest value of $(x-3)^2$, that is $9$. Now, the value of the expression $9(2-a)-9$ must not be less than $-9$. If that remains true, then the value of the expression $(x-3)^2+9(2-a)-9$ always remains positive. Therefore, we get:
$$9(2-a)-9\geq-9$$
$$a\leq2$$
Therefore, the maximum value of $a$ is $2$, that also makes the term $64a$ to be positive.
Thus, the expression $h'(x)$ always remains positive.

why should I ignore that the first cubic term is negative and second term $64a$ is positive and (cubic) + $64a$ $\geq 0$?

That's not the limiting case. I have studied the limiting case here. The case where, first cubic term is negative, second term is positive and the total expression is positive only happens for certain values of $x$ and $a$. If I have considered $a=3$, then for $x=1$ and $x=2$, the total expression is positive, but for $x=3$, it is not. Therefore, it is safe, to choose a certain criteria, where no matter what $x$ is, the cubic term is always positive along with the term $64a$.

$h'(x)\ge0$ for every $x>0$ iff

either $h'$ has one or three (not necessarily distinct) real roots, all $\le0$,
or $h'(x)=4(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)^2$ with $\alpha\le0$.

In the first case, the product $-16a$ of the three roots (in $\Bbb C$, and not necessarily distinct) must be $\le0$, i.e. $a$ must be $\ge0$. But the second case allows larger values for $a$. It happens when the discriminant of $h'$ is $0$. This (after some tedious calculations) is equivalent to
$$a=2\text{ or }0\text{ or }-\frac{10}{27}.$$
$a=2$ is convenient since for this value, $h'(x)=4(x+2)(x-4)^2$.
Verification that the two other roots of the discriminant are indeed $0$ and $-\frac{10}{27}$:

for $a=0$, $h'(x)=4x(x-3)^2$;
for $a=-\frac{10}{27}$, $h'(x)=4\left(x-\frac{10}3\right)\left(x-\frac43\right)^2$.

